# Sql Server 2008 R2 Management Studio - no Intellisense

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can anyone suggest why intellisense is not working.

I am using 2008 R2.

I've seen people here suggest writing the FROM clause first - of course.

I've done Query - Intellisense Enabled.

I've done Refresh Local Cache.

I even installed it all on a whole new hard drive, with fresh OS.

I am at my wits end. It was so good when it worked, so long ago.

Comment: Are you connected to a 2008 database? Even with 2008 SSMS, intellisense will not work if you're connected to a 2005 or earlier database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you just install the Visual Studio 2010 SP1 update?  If so, it's a known issue with SSMS IntelliSense.

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2531482) is the description of the issue.

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2527041) is the solution to the issue.

Comment: Shark you rock. It was VS SP1 that was chasing my intellisense away.

Comment: @onefootswill no problem. You know how I know the solution to that problem? Same thing happened to me :)

Comment: Thanks, fixed the issue. To sum it up, just installed the cumulative SP2 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29848)

Comment: Install on brand new Win 8 system I with VS 2010 and SQL 2008 R2, installed SP2 for SQL and intellisense still doesn't work, :(

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of things that could be wrong.

- you may be connected to a SQL Server 2005 or earlier instance, or SQL Azure
- your script may be too large (Tools / Options / Text Editor / Transact-SQL
  / IntelliSense / Maximum Script Size)
- you may be in SQLCMD mode
- make sure Management Studio is patched to >= @@VERSION of server - service packs are important for client tools too
- third party add-ins may be interfering
- the VS issue @Shark pointed out

My suggestion? Start playing with [SQL Server 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=28145) SSMS. Sure, it's just a release candidate at this point, but I have been using it as my primary management tool for over a year and it is as or more stable than 2008/2008 R2 tools. And IntelliSense has some good improvements as well.

Comment: I haven't even seen SSMS 2012 yet. Is it that good? Now you have my interest sparked.

Comment: I think so. I blogged about it here : https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/11/23/sql-server-11-denali-the-new-vs-shell.aspx note that this was 14 months ago and a lot of the "bad" and "ugly" issues have been fixed. Biggest enhancement for IntelliSense is partial matching. So if you type `dbo.sponge` it will bring up `dbo.add_sponge` and `dbo.edit_sponge` in the auto-complete list.

Comment: Turning off SQLCMD mode did it for me.

Comment: Thank you so much for this - turning off SQLCMD mode default for new query windows did it for me, so happy right now!

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, I tried to reinstall SQL and install latest service pack 2 and install cumulative update but that did not solve the problem.

**What solved the problem was reinstalling visual studio 2010 service pack 1**

Answer (score 0):

It also stopped for me when is was previously working fine. I resurrected it by refreshing intellisense local cache with ctl+shift+R or via SSMS menu items: Edit -> Intellisense -> Refresh Local Cache.