# No debugging in VS without deleteing SUO file first

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, solution

I have a web application project that I originally developed in VS 2008, and I am now developing it in VS 2010.  For some reason, when I set breakpoints, they are not hit by the debugger; it just blows through all the code when I run the project.

I found a partial solution where someone suggested deleting the .suo file for the project after closing Visual Studio.  This worked - ONCE.  That is, after deleting the file, and reoppening the project, breakpoints I have set are hit by the debugger and paused there.  The down side is that this **only works once**.  After I stop the project and run it again, it once again skips all breakpoints.  This is causing me to constantly close my project, delete the .suo file, and reopen the project again (which is obiously extremely annoying).

I have researched this, but I can't find someone that is having the same exact issue as me.  I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how I might get this working without this tedious process.  Thank you!

Comment: Just in case stumbled across this, I did find a resolution for this.  Once I installed SP1 for VS2010 this issue went away.

Comment: Additional note: Apparently VS 2010 SP1 has a known issue where it breaks the intellisense in SQL 2008.  Read about the resolution for this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011526/sql-server-2008-r2-management-studio-no-intellisense