# Visual Studio 2008 is ignoring my breakpoints for my website

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2008 is ignoring my break points all of a sudden. I'm running Visual Studio 2008 with the SP1 installed. If I run a different website (all local) the break points are not ignored.

In my web.config I have:

```
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true">
```

For the life of me I cannot see why it would all of a sudden not work and I really need those break points.

Also, if I change debug to either true or false there is not difference. Break points are always ignored.

I have a page with nothing on it and in the code behind's onLoad I set a BP, when I hit F5 Firefox loads and the page runs as if there were no BP.

I then added a button and in onClick for the button I inserted a BP. Again, there is no stopping. The page loads and runs as if they weren't there.

After setting

```
<compilation debug="false"
```

and then hitting F5 (Start Debugging) VS should have asked to change the web.config to allow debugging. But, it did not.

I have also created a new website, copied my all my site files to the new folder and I get the same results.

I really need your help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try Clean and rebuild? Maybe the code is out of sync

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656344/why-does-visual-studio-2008-skip-over-my-break-points

Comment: Sorry, how do you "Clean" and rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly attaching to your webserver process?

http://abhijitjana.net/2010/07/15/identifying-worker-process-w3wp-exe-iis-6-0-and-iis-7-0-for-debugging-asp-net-application/

Also, try clearing out your temporary asp.net files.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougste/archive/2008/08/11/clearing-out-temporary-asp-net-files.aspx

Usually works for me.